# Write arrayList< model class> into txt file using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to get the data from the **arrayBundlePack** after getting data from enqueue call, I'm trying to use BufferedWriter to the saved data in the **arrayBundlePack** & write in the txt file, but it just won't get the output I wanted.

I'm not sure if that's the way to output an arrayList model class.

Here's the code

```
private ArrayList<BundlePack> arrayBundlePack;

Call<BundlePackRepo> call =  ..............         // api content
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BundlePackRepo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<BundlePackRepo> call, retrofit2.Response<BundlePackRepo> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            BundlePackRepo repos = response.body();
                            BundlePackRepo.bundlepacks[] bundlePacksarray;
                            bundlePacksarray = repos.getBundlePacks();

                            BundlePack bundlePack;
                            for (int a = 0; a < bundlePacksarray.length; a++) {
                                bundlePack = new BundlePack();
                                bundlePack.setPromotion_kit(bundlePacksarray[a].getPromotion_kit());
                                bundlePack.setStock_code(bundlePacksarray[a].getStock_code());
                                bundlePack.setIssue_ref(bundlePacksarray[a].getIssue_ref());
                                bundlePack.setQuantity(bundlePacksarray[a].getQuantity());
                                String sysMod = bundlePacksarray[a].getSys_mod();
                                String modifyDate = bundlePacksarray[a].getModify_dt();
                                try {
                                    bundlePack.setSys_mod(df.parse(sysMod));
                                    bundlePack.setModify_dt(df.parse(modifyDate));
                                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                bundlePack.setStatus(bundlePacksarray[a].getStatus());

                                arrayBundlePack.add(bundlePack);

                                                           //Trying to put out the data to text file

                                String filename = "bundlepack.txt";
                                File txtData = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);
                                FileWriter txtWriter = null;
                                try {
                                    txtWriter = new FileWriter(txtData);
                                    BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(txtWriter);
                                    for (BundlePack bdpack : arrayBundlePack) {
                                        fileWriter.write(bdpack.toString());
                                        fileWriter.newLine();
                                        fileWriter.flush();
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
```

**BundlePack**

```
@Entity
public class BundlePack{
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "promotion_kit")
private String promotion_kit;

@ColumnInfo(name = "stock_code")
private String stock_code;

@ColumnInfo(name = "issue_ref")
private String issue_ref;

@ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
private Integer quantity;

@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
@ColumnInfo(name = "sys_mod")
private Date sys_mod;

@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
@ColumnInfo(name = "modify_dt")
private Date modify_dt;

@ColumnInfo(name = "status")
private String status;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPromotion_kit() {
    return promotion_kit;
}

public void setPromotion_kit(String promotion_kit) {
    this.promotion_kit = promotion_kit;
}

public String getStock_code() {
    return stock_code;
}

public void setStock_code(String stock_code) {
    this.stock_code = stock_code;
}

public String getIssue_ref() {
    return issue_ref;
}

public void setIssue_ref(String issue_ref) {
    this.issue_ref = issue_ref;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Date getSys_mod() {
    return sys_mod;
}

public void setSys_mod(Date sys_mod) {
    this.sys_mod = sys_mod;
}

public Date getModify_dt() {
    return modify_dt;
}

public void setModify_dt(Date modify_dt) {
    this.modify_dt = modify_dt;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "BundlePack{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", promotion_kit='" + promotion_kit + '\'' +
            ", stock_code='" + stock_code + '\'' +
            ", issue_ref='" + issue_ref + '\'' +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            ", sys_mod=" + sys_mod +
            ", modify_dt=" + modify_dt +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**BundlePackRepo**

```
public class BundlePackRepo {

private String count;

private bundlepacks[] bundlepacks;

public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public bundlepacks[] getBundlePacks() {
    return bundlepacks;
}

public void setBundlePacks(bundlepacks[] bundlePacks) {
    this.bundlepacks = bundlePacks;
}

public static class bundlepacks {

    @SerializedName("promotionkit")
    private String promotion_kit;
    @SerializedName("stock_code")
    private String stock_code;
    @SerializedName("iss_ref")
    private String issue_ref;
    @SerializedName("qty")
    private int quantity;
    @SerializedName("sys_mod")
    private String sys_mod;
    @SerializedName("modify_dt")
    private String modify_dt;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    public String getPromotion_kit() {
        return promotion_kit;
    }

    public void setPromotion_kit(String promotion_kit) {
        this.promotion_kit = promotion_kit;
    }

    public String getStock_code() {
        return stock_code;
    }

    public void setStock_code(String stock_code) {
        this.stock_code = stock_code;
    }

    public String getIssue_ref() {
        return issue_ref;
    }

    public void setIssue_ref(String issue_ref) {
        this.issue_ref = issue_ref;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getSys_mod() {
        return sys_mod;
    }

    public void setSys_mod(String sys_mod) {
        this.sys_mod = sys_mod;
    }

    public String getModify_dt() {
        return modify_dt;
    }

    public void setModify_dt(String modify_dt) {
        this.modify_dt = modify_dt;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Dont override toString(). Just use a different function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` to convert each `bundlepack` instance to a string for output.  So you need to an override for `toString` to the `bundlepack` class.  It needs to format the instance in the form that you need for your purposes.

Since you currently haven't overridden that method, your code is currently calling `Object.toString()` ... which only outputs the object's class name and hashcode.

Your IDE may well have a helper to generate a `toString` for a class, based on the fields of the class.

Comment: Hi, I tried override toString() on bundlepack, but it just output only 1 line instead of all the data. I'm not sure why, because the data supposely more than 1000+

Comment: So what did your override method do?

Comment: I'll put it in the BundlePack real quick so you can see

Comment: It has no `toString()` method.

Comment: @Override
public String toString() {
    return "BundlePack{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", promotion_kit='" + promotion_kit + '\'' +
            ", stock_code='" + stock_code + '\'' +
            ", issue_ref='" + issue_ref + '\'' +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            ", sys_mod=" + sys_mod +
            ", modify_dt=" + modify_dt +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
} 

I override toString() on BundlePack already

Comment: OK.  So that should work.  Did you recompile it?  Are you sure you are running the recompiled code?  Set a breakpoint on that method to check that it is being called.

Comment: BTW - you do not need to flush after each line.  Just `close()` the writer when you are finished writing.  (Use *try with resources* to do it ... or you will get a resource leak!!)

Comment: Ok it works like a charm :D thanks! Okay, so I'll just replace the flush() with close() then?

Comment: Use *try with resources*!!  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html